# ICollection property in WebService causes "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

I have a web service:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClassA> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ClassB> Children { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public ClassA Test1();

    [OperationContract]
    public ClassB Test2();
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public ClassA Test1()
    {
        return new ClassA()
        {
        };
    }

    public ClassB Test2()
    {
        return new ClassB()
        {
        };
    }
}
```

When I consume web service and call function Test2(), everything works fine. But function Test1 throws "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" exception.

I need to keep the ICollection type of the property. Any idea why I'm getting this exception and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the DataCollectionContract attribute around Class A?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. but it doesn't help.